# How to set a running date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how I would best do the following in SQL Server.

Say I have a table `Sales`:

| Name | Sales | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 1 | 1-1-22 |
| Ben | 2 | 1-2-22 |
| Sally | 3 | 1-1-22 |
| Ben | 2 | 2-2-22 |
| Peter | 1 | 2-1-22 |
| Sally | 2 | 2-2-22 |
| Peter | 1 | 3-1-22 |
| Ben | 2 | 3-2-22 |
| Sally | 2 | 3-2-22 |

My goal is I want to be able to track every day, from the start of the year until today, a sum of all there sales up to today.

So it should show every day from 1/1/2022 to 4/1/2022. As an example the value of sales every day from 1/3 to 1/31, it should show 1 for Peter, 2 for Ben, 3 for Sally, but by 2/3, it should show 4 for Ben, 2 for Peter, and 5 for Sally. The row for today's date should show  3 for Peter, 6 for Ben, 7 for Sally.

Any help or guidance with this is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Use YEAR(date) to get date and sum over the numeric fields.

Comment: Instead of describing what the desired results should look like it would be better if you could edit your question and show exactly (as a table) what it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that pops out here is that you want a list of every date, presumably even if no sales were on that date.  So that makes me want to first create a date series.  In SQL Server 2022 we can look forward to the new GENERATE_SERIES function but for prior versions, we could use a CTE to generate a list of numbers that you could then call DATEADD with to get an list of incrementing dates.  In the example below, the CTE gives numbers between 0 and 99 (days) but it could easily be extended by copying the "v2" value set lines to v3, v4 , etc., and updating the function (e.g. SELECT n = v3 * 100 + v2 * 10 + v1 ).

The second thing I see is that you want one row to show the value for each person, and makes me think of a crosstab query.
Putting those concepts together, the "simple" version would look something like this.  I've added a temp table at the beginning to simulate your table of sales.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #sales;
CREATE TABLE #sales
(
    Seller VARCHAR(30)
  , SaleCount INT
  , SaleDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #sales
VALUES
  ('Peter', 1, '2022-01-01')
, ('Ben', 2, '2022-01-02')
, ('Sally', 3, '2022-01-01')
, ('Ben', 2, '2022-02-02')
, ('Peter', 1, '2022-02-01')
, ('Sally', 2, '2022-02-02')
, ('Peter', 1, '2022-03-01')
, ('Ben', 2, '2022-03-02')
, ('Sally', 2, '2022-03-02');

WITH 
    numberSeries AS 
        (
            SELECT n = v2.n * 10 + v1.n
            FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v1(n)
            CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v2(n)
        )   
    , dateSeries AS 
        (
            SELECT n
                , CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ser.n, '2022-01-01') AS DATE) AS SaleDate
            FROM numberseries ser
        )
    , distinctSellers AS 
        (
            SELECT Seller
         FROM #sales
         GROUP BY Seller
        )   
SELECT SaleDate
     , [Ben]
     , [Peter]
     , [Sally]
FROM
(
    SELECT d.SaleDate
         , ds.Seller
         , SUM(COALESCE(s.SaleCount, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ds.Seller ORDER BY d.SaleDate) AS RunningTotal
    FROM dateseries AS d
        CROSS JOIN distinctSellers AS ds
        LEFT JOIN #sales AS s
            ON d.SaleDate = s.SaleDate
               AND s.Seller = ds.Seller
    GROUP BY d.SaleDate
           , ds.Seller
           , s.SaleCount
) AS src
PIVOT
(
    MIN(RunningTotal)
    FOR Seller IN ([Ben], [Peter], [Sally])
) AS pvt
```

This produces output like this:
[image: sample]

This might make a good interview question, because it's deceptively simple sounding, but a little tricky to code.  The source query picks up the list of dates, the list of sellers, and the SaleCount, or zero if no sales were recorded.  We need to us a window function ( SUM ... OVER ) in order to get a running total, and not just a total for that day.

Comment: In retrospect, the most inflexible thing about this solution is that it's "hardcoded" for Ben, Peter, and Sally.  What happens when you hire Anastasia?  The query must be edited!  All crosstab queries must face this issue.
One way I've avoided that in the past is to make a portion of the query dynamic.  You can construct the bracketed list of names with a query, and then build up a string that can be executed dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Given this sample data (with unambiguous date formats please!):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SalesData(Name varchar(32), Sales int, Date date);

INSERT dbo.SalesData(Name, Sales, Date) VALUES
(N'Peter',  1, '20220101'),
(N'Ben',    2, '20220102'),
(N'Sally',  3, '20220101'),
(N'Ben',    2, '20220202'),
(N'Peter',  1, '20220201'),
(N'Sally',  2, '20220202'),
(N'Peter',  1, '20220301'),
(N'Ben',    2, '20220302'),
(N'Sally',  2, '20220302');
```

We can use a recursive CTE to get all the dates from the beginning of the year to now, cross join that the individual names from the sales table to get a row per salesperson per date, then use a window clause to get a standard running total to date for each person:

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @yearstart date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@today), 1, 1);

;WITH Days([day]) AS 
(
  SELECT @yearstart UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [day]) FROM Days
    WHERE [day] < @today
),
AllDatesPerPerson AS
(
  SELECT Days.[day], sd.Name FROM Days 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM dbo.SalesData
      WHERE Date >= @yearstart) AS sd
)
SELECT dpp.Name, dpp.[day], COALESCE(SUM(sd.Sales) OVER
  (PARTITION BY dpp.Name ORDER BY dpp.[day] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),0)
FROM AllDatesPerPerson AS dpp
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesData AS sd
ON dpp.Name = sd.Name AND sd.Date = dpp.[day]
ORDER BY dpp.Name, dpp.[day]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366); -- covers up to Dec 31 even on leap years
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13ef2a170f8d678f688cf751c4e4f547)

More on running totals (and why some approaches don't scale as well) [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/grouped-running-totals) and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals).

Answer (score 1):

Most reporting systems will produce charts that understand dates, so you shouldn't need to do this.  But for the case where your reporting system doesn't handle it (like one of mine wouldn't)...

```
create table #sales (
    [Name] varchar(50), 
    [Sales] int, 
    [Date] date
)

insert #sales
values 
  ('Peter', 1, {d '2022-01-01'})
, ('Ben',   2, {d '2022-01-02'})
, ('Sally', 3, {d '2022-01-01'})
, ('Ben',   2, {d '2022-02-02'})
, ('Peter', 1, {d '2022-02-01'})
, ('Sally', 2, {d '2022-02-02'})
, ('Peter', 1, {d '2022-03-01'})
, ('Ben',   2, {d '2022-03-02'})
, ('Sally', 2, {d '2022-03-02'})
;

with sales as (
    select s.[Name]
    , s.[Date]
    , s.[Sales]
    , (
        select sum([Sales])
        from #sales
        where [Name] = s.[Name]
          and [Date] <= s.[Date]
      ) as RunningTotal
    from #sales s
),
dt(i
     , s
     , dt) as 

(
  select 1
  , cast('1/1/' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) as date)
  , cast('1/1/' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) as date)

  union all
  select i + 1
  , c.s
  , dateadd(day, 1, dt)
  from dt c
  where dateadd(day, 1, dt) < dateadd(year, 1, s)

),
d as (
    select dt
    from dt
),
s as (
    select [Name]
    from sales
), 
dim as (
    select s.Name
    , d.dt

    from s
    , d
),
almostthere as (
    select d.[Name]
    , d.dt
    , max(s.[Date]) as 'Date'
    from dim d
      left outer join sales s on s.[Name] = d.[Name]
                        and s.[Date] <= d.dt
    group by d.[Name]
    , d.dt
), 
output as (
select dt.[Name]
, dt.dt
, b.RunningTotal
from almostthere dt
  inner join (
    select [Name]
    , [Date]
    , [RunningTotal]
    from sales
  ) b on b.[Name] = dt.[Name]
     and b.[Date] = dt.[Date]
)

select o.[Name]
, o.dt
, o.RunningTotal
from output o
order by o.[Name]
, o.dt
option (maxrecursion 0)

drop table #sales
```